# I want to create a JMS Consumer Project separately

Tags: java, spring-jms

I want to create a JMS Consumer Project separately by using Spring and We have a web project which posts messages into the Queue.

Is JMS Consumer project suppose to be  `.War` or `.EAR`  or `.JAR` or LIBRARY project to consume Messages from the QUEUE?

Note : Our web project & queue are in one web logic server and JSM Consumer project is going to be in different web logic server.

Answer (score 0):

Any of those works because it's only a matter of implementing one of the Spring message interfaces and defining the JMS listener in Spring.  [MessageDelegate or MessageListener are fairly easy to use.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html)  It sounds like you've already configured JMS connection factories in other servers, which is the hardest part.
Edit: To deploy the message driven object to weblogic, it would need to be packaged in a war or ear.  You can either create the message driven object directly in your war or ear project, or make the jar containing the message driven object a dependency that would be added to the war or ear.

Comment: Thanks Chris!!! but I think, we should use .war or .ear if project has JSPs or JS  or web app files  and here my project is going to have just JMS Consumer implementation. Is not enough, if  I create a .JAR or Lib and deploy it into web logic server?